# Rowmeans with matching column names

Tags: r

How could I calculate the `rowMeans` of a data.frame based on matching column names?

Ex)

```
 c1=rnorm(10)
 c2=rnorm(10)
 c3=rnorm(10)
 out=cbind(c1,c2,c3)
 out=cbind(out,out)
```

*I realize that the values are the same, this is just for demonstration.*
Each row is a specific measurement type (consider it a factor).

Imagine c1 = compound 1, c2 = compound 2, etc. 
I want to group together all the c1's and average there rows together. then repeat for all `unique(colnames(out))`

My idea was something like:

```
avg = rowMeans(out,by=(unique(colnames(out)))
```

but obviously this doesn't work...

Comment: I'd be careful with duplicated column names, because it messes up a lot of things. If possible, it would probably be better to transpose your data frame and add a column called `compound`.

Comment: I'm failing to understand how that would help? I should make it know that each row (in the data above) is a specific measurement.

Comment: My point is that having duplicated column names is bad practice. It should generally be avoided, because some functions that work with data frames will give unexpected output if you have duplicated column names. So, my suggestion was to store the compound name in a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sapply(unique(colnames(out)), function(i)
  rowMeans(out[,colnames(out) == i]))
```

Comment: This works great! exactly what i needed. Only thing was i forgot to use     check.names=FALSE when building my data.frame, so my column names had the silent .1 and .2 added to it.

Comment: I had say `sapply(unique(gsub(".\d+","",colnames(out))), fun...`

Answer (score 1):

As @Laterow points out in the comments, having duplicate column names will lead to trouble at some point; if not here, elsewhere in your code.  Best to nip it in the bud now.

If you are starting with duplicate column names, use `make.unique` on the colnames first to append `.n` where `n` increments for each duplicate starting at `.1` for the first duplicate, leaving the initial unique names as is:

```
colnames(out) <- make.unique(colnames(out));
```

Once that's done (or as OP explained in the comments, if it was already being done by the column-creating function silently), you can do your `rowMeans` operation with `dplyr::select`'s `starts_with` argument to group columns based on prefix:

```
library(dplyr);
avg_c1 <- rowMeans(select(out, starts_with("c1"));
```

If you have a large number of columns, instead of specifying them individually, you can use the code below to have it create a data frame of the rowMeans regardless of input size:

```
 case_count <- as.integer(sub('^c\\d+\\.(\\d+)$', '\\1', colnames(out)[ncol(out)])) + 1L;
    var_count  <- as.integer(ncol(out) %/% case_count);
    avg_c <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = var_count , ncol = nrow(out)));

    for (i in 1:var_count) {
        avg_c[i, 1:nrow(out)] <- rowMeans(select(as.data.frame(out), starts_with(paste0("c", i))));
    }
```

As @Tensibai points out in comments, this solution may not be efficient, and may be overkill depending on your actual data set.  You may not need the flexibility it provides and there's probably a more succinct way to do it.

EDIT1: Based on OP comments 
EDIT2: Based on comments, handle all rowMeans at once 
EDIT3: Fixed code bugs and clarified starting point reasoning based on comments

Comment: OP gives a reproducible example, and having duplicate column names is exactly what the Q is above, so I don't get your first sentence and can't tell for the code even if it seems fitting the Q.

Comment: It does need to have duplicate column names. Each compound was tested more than once = duplicate compound names. Once thing I've noticed is that because the duplicate, R decided to tack on '.1' or '.2' to the duplicate entries...

Comment: If R is adding ".1", ".2" to the column names, then you don't have a problem.  You can simply match on the part before the dot suffix.  They're not actually duplicates.  It means whatever you are creating them with is silently calling `make.unique` as it creates the columns.

Comment: Could be great to tackle the whole problem, addressing each unique column prefix too (repeating the same line again and again to change the prefix by hand sounds a bad practice to me)

Comment: @Tensibai Good call.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Works, but better not have more than 9 coumpounds observed more than 9 times... and that's really overkill IMO

Comment: @Tensibai Edited to fix the 9 limitation.  I get the impression that you're just out to criticize.  Not sure why I have offended so much in my attempts to help, albeit imperfectly.  Would you prefer if I delete my answer?

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay I just give your pointers to makes your answer correct... sorry if you find this offending. I could have just downvote without comment instead for a non working solution...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102621/discussion-between-mekki-macaulay-and-tensibai).